# NSDateFormatter Has a Mind of its own

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdateformatter

I have this Following date Formatter code

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss"];
NSDate *result = nil;
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, 10);
NSError *error = nil;
[df getObjectValue:&result forString:[msgColoums objectAtIndex:4] range:&range error:&error];
NSLog(@"Error in Parsing = %@", error);
INLog(@"Date From DF = %@", [df dateFromString:@"2011-12-14T16:31:26.0000000"]);
```

The code returns `null` for the `dateFromString` message.
The Error is `NSInvalidValue=2011-12-14T16:31:26.0000000`.

If I change the formatting string to

```
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
```

then it will work, so the problem is in the time part.

Will someone please shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss"];
```

to quote the literal `T`